# How to understand $|1+z|<1$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ geometrically?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I am trying to understand how to plot $|1+z|<1$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$, is it a circle centred at real axis $\text{Re}(z)=-1$ with radius $1$?

My question is how can we show it algebraically?

I tried $|1+z|=|1+a+bi|<1$, then I am not sure how to proceed to make it into equation of a circle?

Another question is what if $|1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}|<1$?

I tried $\Big|1+a+bi+\frac{(a+bi)^2}{2}\Big|=\Big|[1+a+\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b^2)]^2+(b+ab)^2 \Big|<1$? I am not sure whether it is a circle. Any hint?

Could somebody please give some help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $z=x+iy$ you have:
$$
|1+x+iy|<1
$$
by definition of [modulus for a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) this means:
$$
\sqrt{(1+x)^2+y^2}<1
$$

squaring.......

And you can do the same also for the other question.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the other question, but it turns out to be too complicated. $\Big|1+a+bi+\frac{(a+bi)^2}{2}\Big|=\Big|[1+a+\frac{1}{2}(a^2-b^2)]^2+(b+ab)^2 \Big|<1$, and I am not sure whether it is a circle. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Clearly it is not a circle. It is a $4$ degree curve....

Answer (score 0):

<strike>**Hint:** For the first, write it as $$|z-(-1)|<1$$
Then you can see it is the set of points less than $1$ unit away from $-1$.</strike>

**EDIT:** Hmm, I see this does not really answer the question. Striking it out since it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

in the first problem |1+z|<1 take the argand plane relative to the point (-1,0) or -1+0i in the argand plane and thus 1+z becomes k(say). now plot point of all complex numbers relative to -1+0i in the imaginary plane with modulus 1 and you get a circle centered at (-1,0). thus all the points within the circle(|k|less than 1) will satisfy the equatins

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you need an algebraic argument. $|1+z|<1$ *means* that the distance of the point $z$ from the point $-1$ is less than 1, so $z$ must lie in the open disk centre $-1$ radius 1. But if you put $z=a+ib$, then $|z+1|<1$ is equivalent to $|z+1|^2<1$ is equivalent to $(a+1)^2+b^2<1$ which is the open disk radius $1$, centred at $-1$.

For the second part you probably do need algebra. The same approach gives $(1+a+(a^2-b^2)/2)^2+(b+ab)^2<1$, which gives the interior of an oval around the point $-1$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's the second question that I still have some doubt. How can you tell it is an oval around point $-1$ without plotting it? I know we need algebra, but it seems a bit messy.

Comment: It is clear directly from the original condition that the points $z=0,-2$ are on the boundary and that $z=-1$ is inside. It is also clear that $z=-1\pm i$ are inside and $z=-1\pm2i$ are outside.